# Filesharing with Monterey server fails for some accounts if Open Directory is active

Tags: osx-server, file-sharing, open-directory

I experience a strange behavior with a totally new installation of Monterey server (using the last version of the Server app).
I activated file sharing (in macOS' sharing settings) and everything worked fine for the admin and a new local test user account. Both could successfully authenticate to the server from a client computer and access files via file sharing.

After that, I activated Open Directory (for the first time) in the server app and experienced some strange things:

1. After I activated Open Directory the file sharing authentication for this very same accounts failed. The login window on the client computer 'shaked' and nothing else happened.
2. Switching Open Directory OFF in the Server App made file sharing work again for this accounts. This was repeatable: when OD was switched ON file sharing failed; when it was switched OFF it worked.
3. I then created two new accounts with either OD switched ON or switched OFF. For BOTH new accounts file sharing worked all the time, regardless of the OD status, while for the two 'old' accounts file sharing continued to work only with OD switched off.

Has anyone an explanation for this behavior? What might be the difference between the old and new accounts and  what do I have to do to get the 'old' accounts work with OD switched ON?

Below, you find screenshots of an old (testlocal) and new (newlocal) user entry in the directory utility. (Note: The different NFSHomeDirectory entry does not matter in this context).

[image: Failing 'old' account]

[image: Working 'new' account]

Comment: I assume that the first user as not synced to the OpenDirectory because it wasn't active at that time. It may help to change that user's password once.